# How do I control the robot without using ROS?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have added the model Pioneer 2DX to an empty world. This model comes with the plugin [DiffDrive](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/9e998023acbb0417ca6214047d0a102c9984b927/plugins/DiffDrivePlugin.hh?at=default).

```
<plugin filename="libDiffDrivePlugin.so" name="diff_drive">
  <left_joint>left_wheel_hinge</left_joint>
  <right_joint>right_wheel_hinge</right_joint>
  <torque>5</torque>
</plugin>
```

Running `gz topic -l` I get the topic:

```
/gazebo/default/pioneer2dxCamera/vel_cmd
```

How do I control the robot without using ROS?

I'm getting crazy figuring out how to publish to topic vel_cmd to control this robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20695/how-do-i-control-the-robot-without-using-ros?/) by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can use [Gazebo Plugins](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=plugins)， which can interact with Gazebo through  Gazebo API. But the data communication way is very like ROS type.

---

Originally posted by [littleghost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4645/littleghost/) with karma: 38 on 2018-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on 2018-10-15**:
Thanks. If I want to control the robot with arrow keys? How can I do it? Thanks.

**Comment by [littleghost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4645/littleghost/) on 2018-10-15**:
If you use ROS, that will be quite easy. But if you don't want to use ROS, then you can check Gazebo API to see if there has keyboard related functions.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2018-10-15**:
You write a plugin like `KeyboardGUIPlugin` which publishes velocity commands. Here's a demo world: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/worlds/simple_arm_teleop.world?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

**Comment by [littleghost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4645/littleghost/) on 2018-10-16**:
This world is appropriate. In fact, there are many places where gazebo is very similar to ROS.